# Why doesnt my html show up in my ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I am trying to add replies to the microposts found in this application
https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_2nd_ed

I think I figured out all of the model and controller stuff but that is besides the point.

When I try to add a reply link to app/views/microposts/_micropost.html.erb. it never works.

```
<li>
  <span class="content"><%= micropost.content %></span>
  <p>this text doesnt show up!</p>
  <span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %> ago.
  </span>
  <% if current_user?(micropost.user) %>
    <%= link_to "delete", micropost, method:  :delete,
                                     confirm: "You sure?",
                                     title:   micropost.content %>
  <% end %>

  <%= link_to "reply", new_comment_path(:micropost_id => comment) %> |

  <p> why isnt this working!!?</p>
</li>
```

as you can see I have tried on lines 3 13 and 15 to add a basic text or a reply link. It never shows up. am I doing this wrong? What format should I put a reply link/even basic text I want to show up in?

Here is my micropost controller code

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user
  before_filter :correct_user,   only: :destroy

  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @micropost.destroy
    redirect_back_or root_path
  end

  private

    def correct_user
      @micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by_id(params[:id])
      redirect_to root_path if @micropost.nil?
    end
end
```

and here is my comments controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController 
  def create 
    @comment = @micropost.comments.new(params[:comment]) 
    if @comment.save 
      redirect_to @user
    else 
      redirect_to @user
    end 
  end 

  def destroy
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_back_or root_path
  end
end
```

Also as requested, here is the show.html.erb file which renders the micropost partial

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div class="row">
  <aside class="span4">
    <section>
      <h1>
        <%= gravatar_for @user %>
        <%= @user.name %>
      </h1>
    </section>
  </aside>
  <div class="span8">
    <%= render 'follow_form' if signed_in? %>
    <% if @user.microposts.any? %>
      <h3>Microposts (<%= @user.microposts.count %>)</h3>
      <ol class="microposts">
        <%= render @microposts %>
      </ol>
      <%= will_paginate @microposts %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please post the error message for your "log" folder

Comment: well there arent any errors. It just doesnt show up.

Comment: please post the content of the erb file which renders the "_micropost.html.erb"

Comment: Are you sure you're editing the file that rails is actually using (the log file tells you which partials are being rendered)

Comment: I just posted it the show.html.erb file where _micropost.html.erb file is rendered. actually the log file doesnt have anything showing that _micropost.html.erb is rendered anywhere. But that doesnt make any sense. Wouldnt it have to? All the other parts of _micropost.html.erb are showing up in the right places.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your controller code?
Usually, you set member variables in controllers so your erb looks like this:

```
<%= @micropost.content %>
```

And your controller like this:

```
def show  
  @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])  
end
```

Comment: does that go in my comments controller or my microposts controller? I am trying to add a reply link to the microposts that leads to a comment input box (kind of like a reply

Comment: Whichever controller renders the erb sets the variables such as @micropost.

Answer (score 0):

In show.html.erb, you have to add the following line to render your 'micropost' partial in show view.

**<%= render 'micropost' %>**